# Read data from Nested csv spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have a requirement like I have a csv file with 3 headers. name, age, address. But the address column value also contain ",".so after I load the csv file I am getting all the value is null.

### input.csv

```
name, age, addresses
Ram,30,"France,street name,75000"
Hari,20,"India,karnataka,Bng,856000"
```

here is the sample code

```scala
val spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("FirstApp")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

val customSchema= StructType(Array(
//                          StructField("name", StringType, true),
                            StructField("age", IntegerType, true),
                            StructField("address", StringType, true)
                          ))

 val data= spark.read
              .option("header", true)
              .schema(customSchema)
              .format("csv")
              .load("user.csv")
data.show()
```

```
+-------+-----+------------+
|name   | age |     address|
+-------+-----+------------+
|   null| null|        null|
+-------+-----+------------+
```

1. Can anyone have any idea how to deal with this data
2. I want address will come in one column.

Inside the double quote address is there which is comma(,) separated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> quote (default "): sets a single character used for escaping quoted
> values where the separator can be part of the value. If an empty
> string is set, it uses u0000 (null character).

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

default value are `"` , are you sur you read the right data correctly ?